# Reactor pattern how it works with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, reactor

I started reading `Vert.x` framework documentation, but i didn't understand how it works and what is a Reactor pattern, i read this article https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-reactor-pattern-thread-based-and-eve   and noticed that instead of general servlet based `(one request one thread)` approch,  Reactor pattern uses `event-driven architecture`  where single thread named `event loop` takes a request put it to some sort of the job queue and provides a handler that will be executed once the task has been finished , and code in handler will be executed by this event loop, so golden rule is -  don't block event loop.

What I don't understand  is , from article:

```
Those handlers/callbacks may utilize a thread pool in multi-core environments.
```

So handlers use thread pool , how this pool is difference from the standard thread pool for example `Servlet's container TOMCAT`. How these two concepts are different from each other in case of `Http server` if both are using Thread pool to manage requests.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget that DZone article. Forget the Reactor pattern. Learn [Asynchronous procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_procedure_call).

There are 2 ways to split all the work in computer to parts: threads and tasks (in Java- tasks are `Runnable`s). Tasks execute on a thread pool when they are ready. And when they are not ready, they do not occupy thread with its huge stack, and we can afford to have millions of tasks in single JVM instance, while 10000 threads in single JVM instance is problematic.

The main problem with tasks is when task needs data which is not ready (not calculated by other task, or not yet arrived via network). In the thread world, the thread waiting for data executes a blocking operation like inputsream.read(), but tasks are not allowed to do this, or they would have occupied too many threads from thread pool and all advantages of task-based programming would be lost. So tasks are augmented with mechanisms which submit that task to the thread pool exactly when all their parameters arrived. Task with such a mechanism is called asynchronous procedure call. All the event-driven architectures are variants of asynchronous procedure call: Vert.x, RxJava, Project Reactor, Akka Actors etc. They just pretend to be something original and not always talk about this.

Comment: Thank for response, may i ask one more question, for example in Vertx I can run blocking jdbc query and provide handler to this method. Does it mean that when this task is wait for response from DB it doesn't use thread from thread pool?

Comment: when a task running on thread pool performs blocking operation like JDBC call (as far as I know, there is no asynchronous JDBC drivers), then it block a thread and number of threads decreases. Alternatively, if thread pool is unlimited,  thread pool allocates another thread, which eventually leads to OOME.

Comment: Can you please clarify. If my task depends on result of jdbc query (which is blocking) and only after that it runs on thread pool, which thread is blocked to wait for jdbc response? Some thread has to wait (to be blocked) for response, right? So, we have blocked thread (doesn't matter in thread pool or not). Where is benefit?

Comment: @ВадимПарафенюк the benefit is that the task waiting for result runs on thread pool only after the result is obtained. While it waits, it does not consume core memory for call stack. If it were a thread and not a task, then it would have consume memory all the way, when waiting for result.
As for that thread which is blocked on JDBC response, indeed there is no difference if it uses dedicated thread or one from thread pool.